# Create a complex model in Prisma

Tags: nest, prisma

I am creating a REST API with NestJS and Prisma and I've encountered some problem.

I am using a PostgreSQL db.

I want to create a model for Recipe which contains an array of Ingredients.

Ingredient is an object based on this model:

```
model Ingredient {
  id   String @id @unique @default(cuid())
  name String @unique
}
```

And I want Recipe to look like that in JSON:

```
{
    "title": "Recipe test",
    "description: "Lorem ipsum",
    "ingredients": [{
        "id": "someId",
        "name": "Ingredient test",
        "amount": "4 tbsp
    }]
}
```

So I want one ingredient in Recipe to be an object like Ingredient, but with an additional property: `amount`. I don't want to create a new ingredient any time a recipe is added, but I want to choose one from the existing list and just apply a new property.

So far, I only was able to create an additional model that was related to Ingredient, but it also created a new table in Prisma and I don't want to do that. Is there a way to do it differently?

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to create a separate table for ingredients and want to store ingredients in the Recipe table. You can store ingredients as a JSON array like this:

```
model Recipe {
  id          String @id @default(uuid())
  title       String
  description String
  ingredients Json[]
}
```

You will be able to store any arbitrary fields like amount to the ingredient object in the Json array.

Here's a [reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields/working-with-json-fields) on how to use JSON fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ability to preserve relations and easily filter data, you need 3 tables.

1: Recipe

2: Ingredient

3: RecipeIngredient

In that third table, you can keep track where do the ingredients go and in what amount. You can also track extra data like "measure" (g, oz, ...).

```
model Recipe {
  id   String @id @unique @default(cuid())
  name String @unique
  RecipeIngredient RecipeIngredient[]
}

model Ingredient {
  id   String @id @unique @default(cuid())
  name String @unique
  RecipeIngredient RecipeIngredient[]
}

model RecipeIngredient {
  id   String @id @unique @default(cuid())
  recipeId String
  ingredientId   String
  amount     String                   
  Recipe     Recipe    @relation(fields: [recipeId], references: [id])
  Ingredient         Ingredient @relation(fields: [ingredientId], references: [id])
}
```

When you query the Recipe books, it will look like this:

```
  const data = await prisma.recipe.findUnique({
    where: { id: myRecipeId },
    include: {
      RecipeIngredient: {
        include: {
          ingredient: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

//You will have to adjust the data, as it contains redudant info about recipe table 

  const adjustFormating = data.RecipeIngredient.map((item) => {
    //Remove info about recipe and id, combine ingredient and amount
    return { ...item.ingredient, amount: item.amount };
  });

  data.RecipeIngredient = adjustFormating;

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
//Output:
//{
//    "title": "Recipe test",
//    "description: "Lorem ipsum",
//    "ingredients": [{
//        "id": "someId",
//        "name": "Ingredient test",
//        "amount": "4 tbsp
//    }]
//}

})
```

While it's not best looking, this will allow you to easily filter your queries based on ingredient data. [Prisma docs for explicit-many-to-many-relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#explicit-many-to-many-relations)